# Entity Framework - Many to many?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

I'm defining a many-to-many relationship as follows:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<GameSessionEntry>().
         HasMany(c => c.Users).
         WithMany(p => p.GameSessionEntries).
         Map(
          m =>
          {
              m.MapLeftKey("SessionId");
              m.MapRightKey("UserId");
              m.ToTable("UserSessions");
          });
```

However, I keep getting:

> The Foreign Key on table 'UserSessions' with columns 'UserId' could
>   not be created because the principal key columns could not be
>   determined. Use the AddForeignKey fluent API to fully specify the
>   Foreign Key.

I'm new to database work and the EntityFramework in general - what is it asking me to do?

Comment: Check if `UserId` column that `Usersessions` table is referring to is a primary key in the `Users` table.

Comment: @PawanNogariya How would I do that? I haven't specified anything explicitly. The PK in on the "User" table is just "Id".

Answer (score 1):

It's the recurring confusion with left and right, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16501355/861716) explanation by Slauma. So you just have to turn around the key names:

```
  m.MapLeftKey("UserId");      // Property in the HasMany call
  m.MapRightKey("SessionId");  // Property in the WithMany call
```

Comment: I'm in my official right now... but looking at the documentation.. that should fix it. Doh! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually go about creating a many to many table (note this requires no fluent api configuration)

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserSession> UserSessions { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserSession> UserSessions { get; set; }
}

public class UserSession
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SessionId{ get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling around with a many-many relationship you should rewrite it to a weak entity set.

If you have for instance this relationship:

[image]

You can redesign it to a weak entity set:

[image]

By doing this you get rid of the many-many relationship and don't have to store the same data in multiple tables.

For more information: http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Education/EDA216/lectures/dbtoh4.pdf
Read the lecture slides about "The Relational Data Model" starting on slide 87/360.

Comment: EF always creates a weak entity in the database, because that's the only way to model a many to many association. But we can choose whether or not to include it in the conceptual model as a class. That choice depends on questions like: does the association have attributes of its own? do we want to use foreign key associations in stead of independent associations? do we want to have direct access to the associations e.g. for deleting them without having to load navigation properties in owner objects?

Comment: Ok, that's nice to know. I just posted this answer because Vaughan Hilts wrote that he's new to database work and I figured that it's good to know good database design (even though it wasn't necessary in this case, but it's always good to know what happens in the background). I don't know the policy regarding answers that don't solve the actual problem, but the more you know!