# Entity Framework ApplicationUser Code First Many to Many List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database of Stores.
STORE

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public List<ApplicationUser> Administrators { get; set; } 
public List<ApplicationUser> Managers { get; set; }
```

This is creating a FK of STORE in ApplicationUser (AspNetUsers), however I need to be able to have a user be a manager at one or more stores.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
[Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
...
[Store_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[Store_Id1] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
```

You can see that a user can only be an Administrator of one Store_Id. I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3 in a Code-First approach, and would like to continue along that route. Is there a simple way to get EF to create the join table the way I want it to, like I have with database first?

Everything in my model is working well up to this point, my Identity provider and all of my custom nonsense are living in the same context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Many to many?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850471/entity-framework-many-to-many)

Comment: Many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework are very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the following for anyone who is in the same boat.

```
public class Store : EntityModel
{
    public List<ApplicationUser> Administrators { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> Managers{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And in IdentityModels

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Store> StoreAdmin { get; set; }
    public List<Store> StoreManager { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

(this also in IdentityModels.cs)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany<Store>(u => u.StoreAdmin)
            .WithMany(s => s.Administrators)
            .Map(us =>
            {
                us.MapLeftKey("StoreId");
                us.MapRightKey("ApplicationUserId");
                us.ToTable("StoreAdministrators");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany<Store>(u => u.StoreManager)
            .WithMany(s => s.Managers)
            .Map(us =>
            {
                us.MapLeftKey("StoreId");
                us.MapRightKey("ApplicationUserId");
                us.ToTable("StoreManagers");
            });
     }
```

I was getting tripped up on the Store having two 'relationships' to the ApplicationUser. Most everything I was seeing was COURSE <=> STUDENT, and not COURSE <=> GOODSTUDENTS and COURSE <=> BADSTUDENTS of type Student. The above seems to work beautifully. I don't really NEED the listing of Stores by user in my application, but it's there. Yippie.

Thanks for the downgrade, DVK. Love the community here.