# Entity Framework and Repository Pattern conceptual difficulties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, onion-architecture

I am making an intranet website using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server 2012. I am making a repository and architecturing with **Onion Architecture**. My problem is that the company in which I am working, already has several Server DBs in which the tables have no relations between each other. Instead, there are tables to map these relations. For example a table User, and a table Document have a table User_joint_Document to make a relation, containing both IDs (IDDocument and IDUser). Now when I write my generic repository:

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```

the problem is the Generic type T makes no sense and I can't affect values in my model using EF queries which is normal, and what would be great would be to have a parent class BaseEntity to have IDs defined for each tables, then I can write:

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
```

And all my table models would inherit from BaseEntity. But that would also mean rewriting the whole DB in a relational manner and mapping every DB POCO manually(correct me if I'm wrong), and I do not have the skillset to do this(there are over 300 tables in the different server DBs and I lack proper knowledge and experience to do this kind of operation).

Is there a way to keep my original DB structure, and still write a Generic Repository? How would one go about doing this?

**EDIT** To clarify my question because @saeb answered partially to my question. Can I have a generic repo without having a parent class for my DB POCOs? Or do I need it in order to then have only ONE repository to rule them all? For example:

```
class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T : class
{
  private readonly ApplicationContext context;
  private DbSet<T> entities;
  public Repository(PrincipalServerContext context)
  {
        this.context = context;
        entities = context.Set<T>();
  }
  public T Get(long id)
  {
     return entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.IDUser == id);
     //This does not work, IDUser isn't recognized

  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The example you've given of `Users` and `Documents` is correct in the database. One user can have many documents so you need a junction table of `User_joint_Document`. That is exactly how a relational database should be structured.

Comment: But if you are using Onion Architecture, there is a package that creates repositories automatically for you, you just have to register them in DataOnion.

Comment: @melkisadek Bah! That's how bad I am at working on DBs. I would've thought you would have something like a 1-1 relationship between both tables or something like that? Maybe that rel'ship is an actual table? Really not my strong side. If I make a parent class with ID's, what's does that relation table become? Since it had IDDocument and IDUser, but now I would have ID only from parent class

Comment: I'm assuming there are PK/FK relationships set in the DB? The junction table creates the 1 to 1 relationship from your Many to Many requirement. It's just a structural way to make the Many => 1 to 1 <= Many. The edmx will abstract this away with navigation properties. It shouldn't affect how the repository works with your POCO classes.

Comment: @melkisadek Nope there aren't any PK or FK in the original DB but when I reverse engineer to get the POCOs, it does put PKs (no FK). I forgot to precise I work with Code First Approach so no EDMX.

Comment: @MihailStancescu What? This exists? Is this what you are referring to? https://sswdataonion.com

Comment: Yes, I'm using their packages and use the unit of work and repositories. All you have to do is to declare the domain classes and their correct EF configuration.

Comment: @MihailStancescu Amazing, I'll get my head into that then thanks!

Comment: Yeah, check their packages and with a bit of customization you can achieve what you need.

Comment: @MihailStancescu I will go without the package finally because I need to understand really how it works and start getting used to all this syntax which is new to me. Any idea how to do what I want in my post edit? I feel like if I want to have a generic repo I need a Parent class to englobe IDs and then access from anywhere no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... has several Server DBs in which the tables have no relations between each other ...

But they *do* have a relationship, a [Many-to-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship, which is defined via that third mapping table (whether that's a *correctly* defined relationship is another topic)

> ... the problem is the Generic type T makes no sense and I can't affect values in my model using EF queries ...

Why doesn't it and why can't you? considering your table examples, you'd have two entities, `User` and `Document` and they'd look like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int IDUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Document
{
    public int IDDocument { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And you can use the fluent API in your context's `OnModelCreating` to set up the relationship via the third table:

```
public class YourContext: DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<Document>(u => u.Documents)
            .WithMany(d => d.Users)
            .Map(userJointDocument =>
                {
                    userJointDocument.MapLeftKey("IDUser");
                    userJointDocument.MapRightKey("IDDocument");
                    userJointDocument.ToTable("User_joint_Document");
                });
    }

    ...
}
```

And then you can query `User`s and `Document`s in your repository as you would if there was a direct relationship between them. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490334/how-to-define-many-to-many-relationship-through-fluent-api-entity-framework) are [more](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) good [sources](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First) to learn more about this if you like.

Comment: Thanks for that precise answer and good docs. I have done this but I still get problems in my repo, I cannot recognize the IDs. I've edited my question to show what my repo looks like

Comment: Can't tag u weirdly

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your problem, there is now way of achieving this without putting at least a base class or an interface to your entities/POCOs

You can play around with expressions for achieving a generic Repository

```
public interface IEntity<T> where T : class
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetByIdPredicate(long id);
}        

public partial class User : IEntity<User>
{
   public int UserID { get; set; }

   public Expression<Func<User, bool>> GetByIdPredicate(long id)
   {
      return (User entity) => entity.UserID == id;
   }
}

class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
  private readonly ApplicationContext context;
  private DbSet<T> entities;
  T dummyEntity;

  public Repository(PrincipalServerContext context)
  {
        this.context = context;
        entities = context.Set<T>();
        dummyEntity = new T();
  }
  public T Get(long id)
  {
     return entities.SingleOrDefault(dummyEntity.GetByIdPredicate(id));
  }
```

There's probably a cleaner way that also gets rid of the `dummyEntity` field

Comment: Oh that's a pretty interesting take on it. I've actually reformulated my question and had another answer here, if ever you're interested, it's all packed in one method using Expression methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591796/does-a-generic-repository-need-a-base-entity-class-to-be-applied-everywhere/44592318#44592318