# Does a Generic Repository need a Base Entity class to be applied everywhere?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, onion-architecture

I am creating an Intranet website with ASP.NET MVC and **Onion Architecture**. I have been implementing the repository pattern but I have a difficulty.

Let's say I have a Document table with IDDocument in it. Then this is my repo(with just one method):

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly PrincipalServerContext context;
    private DbSet<T> entities;
    //Constructor and stuff here
    public T Get(long id)
    {
        return entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.IDDocument == id);//Here is my problem
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot use this since T is not recognized as being from Document table. Solution is to create a BaseEntity:

```
public class BaseEntity{
  public int ID{get;set;}
}
```

Then My Document POCO becomes:

```
public class Document : BaseEntity{ 
   //Properties here
}
```

And my Repo:

```
 class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly PrincipalServerContext context;
        private DbSet<T> entities;
        public T Get(long id)
        {
            return entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);//Here is my problem
        }
    }
```

But **I don't want to do this ideally**. What I like in the generic repo is that it allows me to not repeat the same code for all the different tables (I have 300+). But having a BaseEntity would also mean restructuring alot of what I have already done. 
Is it possible to have a Generic repo that you can apply on any POCO without this BaseEntity class?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you will need at least an interface to give the compiler something about `<T>`

Comment: How do you expect your code to know what `ID` is when your generic class takes `T : class`?

Comment: @DanielA.White Ok thank you

Comment: @maccettura Well that's the whole point of my question ...

Comment: @Flexabustbergson When using generics that have to be a certain shape (i.e have an ID), you need to provide a common type.  Whether this is an interface, an abstract class, or even a regular class that other classes inherit from.  
 At some point you need to figure out a commonality between all your classes, if there isn't one then you shouldn't be using generics to try and force them all to be the same (Unless of course you do not need to access any members/properties in your generic class, then it does not matter what shape they are really).

Comment: @maccettura Alright thanks, they do all have IDs in common, I just need to restructure the way I did things. So in this case where ID is the PK of my tables, in the BaseEntity, am I allowed to use annotation [Key] so that it propagates to children classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the [Queryable.SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534956(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Its second parameter has the type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` so you can build expression manually, using as identifier property as you wish.

Short example:

```
public T Get(long id)
{
    var idName = "ID" + typeof(T).Name; // For Document would be IDDocument
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(id.GetType());
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, idName)
    var idValue = Expression.Constant(id, id.GetType());
    var equal = Expression.Equal(property, idValue);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, parameter);
    return entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Imagine you wrote lambda function `(T obj) => obj.IdProperty == id`.
Here `obj` is `parameter`, and `idName` should store `"IdProperty"` string.
`property` means `obj.IdProperty`, `idValue` means the value if `id`.
`equal` means `obj.IdProperty == id`, and predicate means whole expression `(T obj) => obj.IdProperty == id`.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you sir!

Comment: This is getting bookmarked. It's the first time I've seen expression trees explained in a way that really makes how useful they are click.