# Instance Property is not defined for type 'System.Int64'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using a Repository Pattern to access data using Entity Framework. I have implemented everything correctly (I think) using an onion architecture, but when I run tests I get the error :

```
Instance Property 'IDDocument' is not defined for type 'System.Int64'
```

(roughly translated from french)

The method I test is the following:

```
public T Get(long id)
{
    ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    ObjectSet<T> set = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    IEnumerable<string> keyNames = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                                .KeyMembers
                                                .Select(k => k.Name);
    if (keyNames.Count() > 1)
        return null;//Que faire quand il y a plusieurs clés?
    else
    {
        string idName = keyNames.ElementAt(0); // For Document would be IDDocument
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(id.GetType());
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, idName);
        var idValue = Expression.Constant(id, id.GetType());
        var equal = Expression.Equal(property, idValue);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, parameter);
        return entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

My tables have different ID names for reasons I won't explain, but this is why I used Expression builder to add parameters and then use a predicate to retrieve my result. You can see this method in this post: [Does a Generic Repository need a Base Entity class to be applied everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591796/does-a-generic-repository-need-a-base-entity-class-to-be-applied-everywhere/44592318#44592318)

IDDocument is declared in the following way in my EF entities' POCO:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public long IDDocument { get; set; }
```

And when I call it in my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IdExistsGetTest()
{
    long valueToCheck = 1L;
    repo = new Repository<Web_Documents>(context);
    var test = repo.Get(valueToCheck);
    test.Should().BeOfType(typeof(Web_Documents));
}
```

`context` defines my dbcontext (instantiated before).

Now when I run the tests, I always get the ArgumentException stated above, any idea what I am missing? I think the problem resides in the Get(long id) method, because if I change the code without the `Expression`, it works fine (but not like i want it to!). Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(id.GetType());
```

Should be:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
```

Comment: Right on, thanks! I do have another question though, when checking the type of `entities.SingleOrDefault(predicate)` I do not get `Web_Documents`but something like `Web_Document_8AEAF73BFA0B4906B5153F0BE5CFE91F2DC7F47643CDC9E48189AC7C08E041D2.`. I don't understand why? Must have not understood SingleOrDefault properly.

Comment: What you are seeing is the EF proxy type (a wrapper around your type that provides lazy loading and object tracking). The proxy type inherits from your type so you can explicitly cast this to your type if required. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592886(v=vs.113).aspx