# Entity Framework6 2 * many-to-many to self

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Using code-first with Entity Framework 6.

I've this entity:

```
public class LineSection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<LineSection> Next { get; set; }
    public List<LineSection> Previous { get; set; }
}
```

I add a migration, just to see how the database will be:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.LineSectionLineSections",
            c => new
                {
                    LineSection_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    LineSection_Id1 = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LineSection_Id, t.LineSection_Id1 })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.LineSections", t => t.LineSection_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.LineSections", t => t.LineSection_Id1)
            .Index(t => t.LineSection_Id)
            .Index(t => t.LineSection_Id1);
```

I don't like the default naming. Can I change the tablename (LineSectionLineSections) and the two foreignkeys (LineSection_Id and LineSection_Id1). Using modelbuilder, data attributes or some other way?

Comment: `MapLeftKey`, `MapRightKey`. There are many examples, for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490334/how-to-define-many-to-many-relationship-through-fluent-api-entity-framework

Comment: Please show a complete example for my case. As far as I can see, your examples doesn't fit my case as there is only list in the entity and not two.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration on many-to-many relationship with implicit join table (doesn't matter if t is self or not) is performed with `Map` fluent API. You can use `ToTable` to specify the table name and `MapLeftKey` / `MapRightKey` to specify the corresponding column names (left is the entity being configured, right is the other end of the relationship).

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LineSection>()
   .HasMany(e => e.Next)
   .WithMany(e => e.Previous)
   .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("PrevId")
          .MapRightKey("NextId")
          .ToTable("LineSectionLinks")
   );
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand it, but it works great :-)